# React useState not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set up authenticated routes in react and have a useState hook to change to true once the user is authenticated. When I get the user data from my server, I can update the current user information but the useState hook for my authentication will not change from true to false and vice versa.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import ApiHandler from "../ApiHandler/ApiHandler";

const api = new ApiHandler();
export const useAuth = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = userContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    api
      .get("/is-loggedin")
      .then(res => {
        setCurrentUser(res.data.currentUser);
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      });
  }, [setCurrentUser]);
  return { isLoggedIn, currentUser };
};
```

Comment: It would be better to see your `userContext` code, because a lot depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is useEffect 2nd argument `dependencies array` does not have correct dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => { /* rest of the code */ }, [setCurrentUser]);
```

change to

```
useEffect(() => { /* rest of the code */ }, [setCurrentUser, isLoggedIn]);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but it is still having issues. The console states "index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.". I have tried to "clean up effects" as searched on google again with no success. Any further assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method inside the hook, and then call. Add the three lines having comments. Also `currentUser` is the dependency because if user changes then will you check if it's logged-in. Your mistakes were

1)- passing `setCurrentUser` (it will never change as it's a function/handler) in dependency.
2)- neither declared the method nor called it, instead just passing statements to `useEffect`, which only runs once.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import ApiHandler from "../ApiHandler/ApiHandler";

const api = new ApiHandler();
export const useAuth = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = userContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    function getStatus() { //method body starts
      api.get("/is-loggedin")
      .then(res => {
        setCurrentUser(res.data.currentUser);
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      });
   }; //method body closed.
   getStatus(); //this is the call
  }, [currentUser]);
  return { isLoggedIn, currentUser };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put  an empty array to useEffect

```
          useEffect(() => {
            api
              .get("/is-loggedin")
              .then(res => {
                setCurrentUser(res.data.currentUser);
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                setCurrentUser(null);
                setIsLoggedIn(false);
              });
          }, []);
```